# Assigning a CRS to a LAS

Tags: python, coordinate-system, las, point-cloud, pdal

Is there a way to assign CRS to the LAS file through Python if the name of CRS is corrupted and looks like following?

[image]

Comment: Seems like _GCS_Pulkovo_1942_GOST_32453-2017_, encoded in a character map but read in another.

Comment: so, how can it help to me?

Comment: Seems to be a geographic Pulkovo 1942 coordinates system, but I don't understand the language of the GOST 32453-2017 document, which seems to provide transformation parameters to define the abridged transformation to a bound crs, probably WGS84. It is what in version 4 of PROJ was determined with the *+towgs84* option. If you could know not only the name but the definition of the CRS, surely that is what it is and you will see the parameters there.